# How to run node server and java server in same command line in package.json start

Tags: java, node.js, linux, npm, package.json

I need to run :

```
node server.js
```

And :

```
java -Xmx4g -cp 'libraries/corenlp/*' edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLPServer -serverProperties StanfordCoreNLP-french.properties -port 9000 -timeout 15000
```

I tried :

```
node server.js; java -Xmx4g -cp 'libraries/corenlp/*' edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLPServer -serverProperties StanfordCoreNLP-french.properties -port 9000 -timeout 15000
```

Or

```
node server.js && java -Xmx4g -cp 'libraries/corenlp/*' edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLPServer -serverProperties StanfordCoreNLP-french.properties -port 9000 -timeout 15000
```

But in both case the java server is not running when I ask it in the node applicaition. But if I run both commande in 2 differents console.
There is no problem.
Thank you

Edit: I try to do it in the npm start

Comment: Which OS you are using to run these processes?

Comment: @KrishnaKuntala Debian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so I found a way to do it :
My package.json:

```
"scripts": {
    "start-nlp" : "java -Xmx4g -cp 'libraries/corenlp/*' edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLPServer -serverProperties StanfordCoreNLP-french.properties -port 9000 -timeout 15000 &",
    "start-node": "node server.js",
    "start": "npm run start-nlp && npm run start-node"
```

},

Answer (score 0):

You need to run the processes in the background. Please append `&` at the end of the commands to run them in the background.

```
node server.js &

java -Xmx4g -cp 'libraries/corenlp/*' edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLPServer -serverProperties StanfordCoreNLP-french.properties -port 9000 -timeout 15000 &
```

To kill them, you need to search these processes using `ps -ef | grep` command.

Comment: I try to run it from npm start and I got : sh: 1: Syntax error: ";" unexpected